# Load image from image url to show animation in UIImageview

Tags: ios, animation

I m getting more than 200 image url from web service and i am converting image url to `UIImage` array and showing animation in `UIImageView` and its crashing in device and its working fine in simulator? Can you plz provide any solution for this issue.

Comment: Relevant code would be better to understand crash cause.

Comment: check if any memory issue or what?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle this job by using the native API:

`[UIImage +animatedImageWithImages:(NSArray *)images duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration]`

Comment: This is not working for me. I am using below line                        QHTTPOperation * op = [[QHTTPOperation alloc]initWithURL:url withKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i]];                               for converting image url to UIImage and it is showing memory leak on this particular line.